# Monotonicity of a special function

Tags: calculus

Assume $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $\rho\in\mathbb{N}$. Define
$$f(k):=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\frac{i\rho^i}{i!}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}}-\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{i\rho^i}{i!}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}}$$
Show that $$f(k)\geq f(k+1)\qquad \forall k\in\mathbb{N} $$

Note that this function is discrete so we cannot take derivatives to prove the monotonicity.

My attempt: After some manipulation, the inequality is equivalent to:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}+\frac{\rho^2}{k(k+1)}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}\geq \frac{2\rho}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}
$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Where does this function come from?